# SELECT WHERE Between SELECT Dates from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to find out if this can be made simpler/shorter. It is working but i think i can be faster,  more efficient or cleaner.

```
SELECT Tbl_VSchedTime.* 
FROM CalendarScheduled
INNER JOIN Tbl_VSchedTime ON CalendarScheduled.[EID] = Tbl_VSchedTime.[EID]
WHERE ([Tbl_VSchedTime].[SchdDate] Between (SELECT MIN(CalendarScheduled.[SchdDate]) FROM CalendarScheduled) And (SELECT MAX(CalendarScheduled.[SchdDate]) FROM CalendarScheduled));
```

This is my test Select that will actually be change to Delete. In short I am selecting from Tbl_VShedTime anything matching the EIDs on the INNER JOIN and between the min and max dates in CalendarScheduled. However am forced to use a SELECT under each of the dates for it to work. It wont just work by using MIN and MAX when I have already "conjured" the table on the FROM Statement.

Is this just how I have to use it in access or did I miss something? Thanks.

Edit: The question is: Why can't I just write:

`WHERE ([Tbl_VSchedTime].[SchdDate] Between MIN(CalendarScheduled.[SchdDate]) And MAX(CalendarScheduled.[SchdDate]))`

Comment: What problem are you asking for help with?

Comment: Why cant I just write:
`WHERE ([Tbl_VSchedTime].[SchdDate] Between MIN(CalendarScheduled.[SchdDate]) And MAX(CalendarScheduled.[SchdDate]));`

Comment: Can't do the latter because you want individual records. Aggregate functions are used in an aggregate query. You are not aggregating data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider joining the aggregate query and then use aggregates in `WHERE` condition. Because aggregates return one row, cross join them with your current query which in MS Access means comma-separation in `FROM`:

*CROSS JOIN Before INNER JOIN*

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM 
(SELECT MIN([SchdDate]) AS MinDate, MAX([SchdDate]) AS MaxDate
 FROM CalendarScheduled) AS agg
,
CalendarScheduled c
INNER JOIN Tbl_VSchedTime t ON c.[EID] = t.[EID]
WHERE (t.[SchdDate] BETWEEN agg.MinDate AND agg.MaxDate;
```

*CROSS JOIN After INNER JOIN*

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM 
 (CalendarScheduled c
  INNER JOIN Tbl_VSchedTime t ON c.[EID] = t.[EID])
,
(SELECT MIN([SchdDate]) AS MinDate, MAX([SchdDate]) AS MaxDate
 FROM CalendarScheduled) AS agg
WHERE (t.[SchdDate] BETWEEN agg.MinDate AND agg.MaxDate;
```

Comment: And hopefully, one day soon MS Access will catch up to its database peers and support current ANSI standards like `CROSS JOIN`. Please encourage the Access team to update its SQL dialect by [voting on this post](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar) (login not required)!

Comment: This does it, thank you. Just voted on having access updated. However I doubt it will happen, it's one MS SQL Server sell point.